# Searching ElasticSearch with dynamic field names

Tags: elasticsearch, search, dynamic, field

I have a method to search in C# as follows:

```
public void Search(string data)
        {
            var searchResponse = client.Search<Products>(s => s
                .From(0)
               .Size(100)
               .Query(q => q
                 .Match(m => m
                     .Field( f => f.ProductName)
                      .Query(data))));
             int cnt = searchResponse.Documents.Count;
        }
```

This returned 5 documents, which is valid.

But, I wanted to modify the above method as follows, so that I can pass the field to be searched dynamically.

```
public void Search(string data,string fieldName)

    {
            var searchResponse = client.Search<Products>(s => s
                .From(0)
               .Size(100)
               .Query(q => q
                 .Match(m => m
                     .Field(fieldName)
                      .Query(data))));

            int cnt = searchResponse.Documents.Count;

        }
```

The above code does return any error, but return 0 documents.

Here I am passing `ProductName` to `fieldName` parameter. I know this will not work. I just want tell my intention here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Field Infering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html)

You can pass below to your query

var fieldString = new Field("fieldName");

```
var fieldString = new Field("fieldName");
var searchResponse = _elasticClient.Search<AllOpportunitySearchResult>(s => s
                                   .From(0)
                                   .Size(100)
                                   .Query(q => q
                                                .Match(m => m
                                                             .Field(fieldString)
                                                             .Query(data)
                                                      )
                                         )
                      );
```